# What does the phrase "chuck something in" mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, australian-english

I was doing the bilingual subtitling for a video recorded last year, on the first day of same-sex marriage debate in the lower house of Australia. There was a marriage proposal from an MP to his partner. After his partner's "yes", Tim said, "We'll chuck that in the memoirs and Hansard."

At first I thought "chuck that in" here means "keep it in", however, according to the this [news report](https://aplus.com/a/australia-parliament-tim-wilson-proposal?no_monetization=true/%20news%20repot%20on%20a%20), it seems that "chuck" means "delete".

On Oxford Dictionary, the word CHUCK means:*to throw carelessly or casually*, and it can be used with both prepositions *in* or *out/away*, but with opposite meanings, which is why the interpretation of that news report seems odd to me.
I'm really confused here. :( Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Next time, please use full words rather than "sth".

Comment: @curiousdannii OK! I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

It's colloquial Australian for *put*. The term carries the notion of throwing something somewhat carelessly, but the intent is simply to have something included or placed.

Compare from the same page ([Talk Like a True Aussie](https://www.goldcoastbulletin.com.au/lifestyle/talk-like-a-true-aussie-top-10-aussie-sayings-and-what-they-mean/news-story/d216f699ddee5bd0ed643d9244a336be)):

- chuck a shrimp on the barbie
- Put a shrimp on the Barbie

So "We'll chuck that in the memoirs and Hansard" says to *put* that into the documents.

Comment: @Hawk No worries, mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible interpretations of the phrase as written:

> A We'll "chuck that in" the memoirs and Hansard.
>
> B We'll "chuck that" [in the memoirs and Hansard].

In A the phrase "chuck that in" means "put that in". In B the phrase "chuck that" means "get rid of that" and "in the memoirs and Hansard" means "with respect to the memoirs and Hansard".

The news article you linked seems to have taken interpretation B. When it comes to Hansard (the official record of what is said in parliament), it's unclear whether meaning A or meaning B was intended. When it comes to someone's memoirs, why on earth would they not include something like this? When you've just done something ground-breaking, that you've been campaigning for for ages, you're going to record it and celebrate it! Therefore from context A is the only likely interpretation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! That's also the only reasonable interpretation I can come up with.